# How to loop through and return the values of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-map-gl

(Apologies if some of my terms aren't correct)

In Firebase I have a number of posts. Each post has a 'latitude' field and a 'longitude' field. I am pulling these out and storing them in an array/object called mapRefs:

```
useEffect(() => {
    projectFirestore.collection("posts").get().then(res => {
        let mapRefs = [];
        res.forEach(data => {
            mapRefs.push([data.data().myLatitude, data.data().myLongitude]);    
        });
        console.log(mapRefs);

        });
}, []);
```

This works, the output for the console log is:

```
0: (2) [-8.6848548, 115.22303799999999]
1: (2) [-8.7848548, 115.323038]
2: (2) [-8.9848548, 115.52303799999999]
3: (2) [-8.8848548, 115.42303799999999]
```

How do I then iterate through these and map a latitude and longitude value to a component. I was trying like this:

```
<ReactMapGL>
    { mapRefs && mapRefs.map(coord => (
        <Marker latitude={coord[0]} longitude={coord[1]}>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        </Marker>
    ))}
</ReactMapGL>
```

This isn't working. What would be the correct way to do this, please?

Comment: "Isn't working" in what way? Do you get errors? Wrong data? Something else?

Comment: Hi Guy, ah, sorry, I missed that bit.  It's not outputting anything, probably due to the 'mapRefs &&' conditional thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use [state values](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook) to render the UI elements and `mapRefs` is not available outside `useEffect`.

try like this

```
const [mapRefs, setMapRefs] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    projectFirestore.collection("posts").get().then(res => {
       let refs = [];
       res.forEach(data => {
          refs.push([data.data().myLatitude, data.data().myLongitude]);    
       });
       setMapRefs(refs)
    });
}, []);

return (
  <ReactMapGL>
    { mapRefs.map(coord => (
        <Marker latitude={coord[0]} longitude={coord[1]}>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        </Marker>
    ))}
</ReactMapGL>
)
```

Comment: Hello Naren, thanks for your help. I'm getting a 'res.map is not a function' error.

Comment: How does this working working then? `res.forEach(data => {
            mapRefs.push([data.data().myLatitude, data.data().myLongitude]);    
        });``

Comment: Changed your logic, check now!

Comment: Super my friend, you're an absolute star ⭐ (And I think I understand it too.) Thank you, and have a great day!

Comment: Glad to help, Have a nice day too!